# Ruby IO does not work on Windows as expected, randomly stucks on puts and read

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, io, pascal

I am trying to write a simple checker for students' tutorial console application. It should run under Windows as a standalone application.

Having some experience with Ruby, I wrote the following code:

```
require 'yaml'
progs = YAML.load_file "test.yaml"
progs.each do |prog|
  puts "running #{prog}..."
  pn = prog["program"]
  tc = 0
  prog["tests"].each do |i, o|
    tc += 1
    puts "Test #{tc}:\n" #{i}\n=>\n#{o}\n--\n"
    IO.popen(pn, "r+") do |pie|
      #pie.sync = true
      pie.puts i
      #pie.flush
      #pie.close_write
      a = pie.read
      if a != o
        puts "ERROR: wrong output on test #{tc}"
        puts "Input: #{i.inspect}"
        puts "Expected: #{o.inspect}"
        puts "Actual:   #{a.inspect}"
        puts
      else
        puts "ok"
      end

    end

  end
end
```

Supporting YAML file looks as follows:

```
---
- program: summax.exe
  tests:
    "2\r\n 0 0\r\n": "0\r\n0\r\n"
    "4\n 100 1000 -100 -1000": "0\n1001\n"

- program: ./summax
  tests:
    "2\n 5 6": "11\n6\n"
```

On Linux, this just works, even when running exe compiled with ABC Pascal (via Wine and some binfmt magic I suppose). On target platform, Windows, the same code gets stuck after printing "Test 1:" line, and if I break it with ^C, it can proceed to test 2 or output some more strings and then die with `tester.rb:20:in 'puts': Interrupt` (or any other puts, or even read).

Uncommenting all those lines with `sync = true, flush and close_write` do not seem to help. Changing `read` to `read_lines.join` too. Even flushing on the other side with `flush(output); close(output);` does not resolve that. What else should I try, or is it simpler to just rewrite this program on something more native to Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Ruby side of the pipe, [ProcessPilot](http://processpilot.sourceforge.net/rdoc/latest/ProcessPilot.html#method-c-pilot) gem solves Windows IO.popen issue. ABC Pascal does not seem to work nicely with redirected IO streams, so using FPC instead solved this other problem.

Standalone application built with Ocra works just fine on a Windows machine without Ruby installed. I had to launch build process as `ocra --gem-minimal tester.rb` to fix yaml/psych issue.

Comment: I can vaguely remember that if the process is started with inherited handles, you get this isssues. I don't know ABC Pascal (I prefer FPC too), but if it allows you to modify the RTL, you might fix it.